# Angular 5 opening a specific module in a new tab without loading all other modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular-module

I am developing an angular 5 application using WebApi2 for the back-end. Until now I have had a single module application. But now we have decided to optimize our application by dividing it into multiple modules and use lazy loading.

I am trying to move the Reports section of our application into a separate module and I want my reports to be opened in a new browser tab without loading all the other modules in order to improve the loading time of the reports.

I have tried to implement this using lazy loading and it is opening my reports in the new tab but still it is loading all the other modules again.

This is the link which I am using in my header menu template:

```
<li [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['reportdashboard']" target="_blank" [queryParams]="{ rt: 'business'}"> Business Reports</a></li>
```

This is the lazy loaded route which is lazily loading my `ReportsModule`:

```
 { path: 'reportdashboard', loadChildren: './modules/reports/report.module#ReportsModule' },
```

Below is my app.module file code which displays different modules:

```
import {SharedModule} from './modules/shared/shared.module';
```

I have added this SharedModule in the imports property of @NgModule in app.module.ts.
And I am lazy loading the ReportsModule and it does not required and imports in the app module. I have added its route above in the description.

Comment: Not aware of any way to load only one feature module on a new window. What you may do is splitting your application so that the reports module may be loaded directly from the AppModule, but you would still need to load your application and the AppModule prior to loading it. Another option is packing your reports using [angular elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements), so that you may have a component that does not depend on angular application to load and run.

Comment: You say you divided your app to multiple modules. Can you show your `app.module`  file and your app routes ?

Comment: Thanks @GCSDC , but I am using a shared module which has all the common services, utilites,directives, interfaces,etc. And I am using it in both my appModue(main module) as well as Report Module(Featured Module).So, If I create an angular element out of it.How I would be able to manage this requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Michal, currently I am having 3 modules : 1. appModule. 2. Shared Module. 3. ReportsModule.  I have added my app.module file code and routes in the question description.

Comment: app module is your root module. Your app can't work without it. shared module is used everywhere, so it's loaded too. And reports module is loaded becaue the URL matches its path. If you want to load less things, you need to create an additional, lazy-loaded module, for all the non-reports routes of your application. But anyway, since the main JS bundle of the app module has already been loaded by your first tab, opening a new tab should just load it from the browser cache, so why do you bother?

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, I have done a lot of research on it and found out I can use Service worker in order to load pages from cache.

Comment: Sure, but this is a different matter. The browser has a cache and uses it, without having to to anything in your code, to store static assets like JavaScript files. If it has already loaded a JS file previously, then unless you have cleared your cache or explicitly told the browser via response headers to not cache the JS file, then it will load it from there.

Comment: I know about the Browser cache, but in my case on opening reports in different browser tab whole html page(index.html) is loading again due to which all the other modules are also getting loaded along with it. I want that my other modules should not get load.

Comment: They're loaded, but they're loaded from the browser cache. So it's instantaneous and doesn't cost anything. So why does it matter?

Comment: Yep, I agree with u @JBNizet on this. But How would I be able to implement this scenario now so that my other main modules should not get loaded while loading reports in different browser tab. Is this possible or not?

Comment: I already told you how: you need to create an additional, lazy-loaded module, for all the non-reports routes of your application

Comment: I applied a different approach, I created a small separated project for reporting, all reports are html templates and all them get the data from localstorage. In the main SPA I provided buttons to show reports, each button action prepare the data and save it in the localstorage, after that opens in another tab the reports-application with specific path.
As as secondary effect, from the development point of view, the report project only needs mock JSONs to develop without any other server, then I could separate the responsability.
myproject/ui -> Main SPA
myproject/reports -> Small Reports

Comment: @AnkitMakhija I want to achieve the same thing, did you find a solution?